# How come java is in my path but not javac?

Tags: java

I am running Windows 7.

In command line, in anywhere if I type java I will get:

[image]

which is very nice..

But when I type javac I get:

[image]

Here is my environmental variables:

[image]

What is it that I am doing wrong?

User variables:

[image]

Comment: Seems like `javac` is not in `/system32`. Is the `JAVA_HOME` on your path?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin needs to be added to your Path

Comment: Do you have the JRE in your path, but not a JDK?  The JRE contains `java` but not `javac`.

Comment: @RayStojonic Thanks Ray, can you answer so I can accept?

Comment: Why is this not a real question?

Comment: Based off your path, it looks like neither javac or java should be on there, which makes me think that you might've put it in your user PATH rather than your system path, which is what you're showing us.

Comment: @RankWeis I have added my user variables.

Comment: No Path at all, I'd be very interested in finding out why java worked, if anybody knows

Comment: @RankWeis possibly a JVM that came with the several different servers that he has installed that has "java" in them?

Comment: @RankWeis I have no idea myself too :) In Control Panel when I search for Java there is an icon there. Maybe it is the java from jre. How it works, I honestly do not know.

Comment: @RankWeis There is a java.exe under: C:\Windows\System32 Mystery solved..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin needs to be added to your Path

Edit: %JAVA_HOME%\bin really is the better option - assuming the jdk installer can be trusted to update JAVA_HOME, it becomes a 'set it and forget it' situation.

Comment: @KorayTugay I actually think the other answer is more correct. What's the point of having a JAVA_HOME variable, if you don't use it?

Comment: @Cruncher Well his first answer was really wrong and he kind of got hint from Ray.. So hats off to Roy Harper this time.. I upvoted both anyway.

Comment: @KorayTugay more that I forgot the \bin, but it's no biggie either way.  Glad we could help

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the installed JDK to your PATH.  In your tree up there, you have JAVA_HOME set, just add %JAVA_HOME%\bin to your PATH variable.

This is because Java's JRE (Java Runtime Environment) and JDK (Java Development Kit) are separate installations.

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25` sounds like a JDK to me

Comment: Good catch, I didn't see that.  Deleted that part of my answer

Comment: Adding %JAVA_HOME% only did not help.

Comment: It has to be %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Comment: Using %JAVA_HOME% is generally the preferred solution in my experience as it makes it easier to update to new versions of Java without having to modify your PATH every time, which is more painful than modifying JAVA_HOME just due to the typical length of PATH (at least in most versions of windows... I've not seen that tree view of environment variables before... is that new with Win8 or something?)

Comment: @KorayTugay cool, looks handy.  Too bad I'm not allowed to download stuff on my work computers lol :)

Comment: @KorayTugay that looks handy

Answer (score 0):

this Please enter in cmd

SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin

Comment: This will only work in a single command window, will not update the system variables, so is not a good solution as the next time you open a command window you'd have to `SET` it again